# apache zeppelin throwing NullPointerException error

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am new to zeppelin and trying to setup the zeppelin on my system.
Till now I have done the following steps:

1. Downloaded zeppelin from [here](http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html)
2. Setup the JAVA_HOME at my system environment variable.
3. Goto zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all\bin and ran zeppelin.cmd
4. Able to see zeppelin-ui at http://localhost:8090

When I am trying to run `load data into table` program mentioned in zeppelin tutotial -> Basic Features(spark) it is throwing following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:398)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:387)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:843)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The above mentioned error log i am able to see in output inside zeppelin-ui at the same time my console (cmd) shows following error:

```
DEBUG [2018-01-11 10:55:30,059] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:206) - DEBUG [2018-01-11 10:55:30,059] ({pool-1-thread-3} Interpreter.java[getProperty]:165) - key: zeppelin.spark.concurrentSQL, value: false
 WARN [2018-01-11 10:55:30,061] ({pool-2-thread-2} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2064) - Job 20150210-015259_1403135953 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: null, result: %text java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:398)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:387)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:843)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there anything that I am missing or anything to do with spark? Because I am assuming zeppelin will take care of spark and we do not have to setup the spark. Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: @ShankarKoirala No. Where I have to add this ?

Comment: run `bin\zeppelin.cmd` outside of the bin directory.

Comment: @1ambda let me try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would ensure that spark is generally running.

Have you tried to run a new "spark notebook".

1. create new notebook
2. select spark as default interpreter
3. just run a paragraph with "sc" in it

It tries to initialize a sparkcontext. 
When it works we are good and we need to check the options an syntax which is used in the paragraph you are using.

If that is not running i would check/set the zeppelin-env.cmd with the following variables:

- SPARK_HOME
- JAVA_HOME
- HADOOP_CONF_DIR (if using hadoop)

If you didnt setup spark on windows yet it can not work.

1. download the spark version you like to use https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
2. unzip it in a folder of your choice (e.g.windows c:/hadoop/sparkVERSION)

If all those steps dont work, please show me the output and code you try to run.

BR

**UPDATE** 
Following post exactly desribes how to setup zeppelin on windows to run the tutorials.

https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/

I just went through it on my windows machine and it worked fine for me.

Comment: can you please provide the erros and messages?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)

Comment: it is same as I mentioned in my question

Comment: Can I set SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: If yes what I have to set for SPARK_HOME ?

Comment: as you are using the zeppelin.cmd im assuming that you running on windows.

you should got through:
https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/

and after that :
https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/

then all should be running perfectly on your windows machine

Comment: Yes I am using zeppelin.cmd on windows! Let me try your refs. and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Zeppelin 0.8 on HDP 3.1 with spark 2.3 and I think the issue was in overriding libraries, which are already present in spark interepreter.

The code is working with Kafka DirectStream, but it is not important for this issue.

See, what I have commented and it worked.

```
%spark2.dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("MavenCentral").url("https://mvnrepository.com/")
z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0")
z.load("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.3.0")
//z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.3.0")
//z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.2")
//z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.2")
```